# AppCompatActivity not found. Nothing worked

Tags: android, android-appcompat

It's 3 days, 8h a day that I'm trying everything to make this stuff work but without any success.

I keep getting "AppCompatActivity not found". I don't know why. Any idea?

That's the code:

```
public abstract class DroidActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

And that's the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:External:ErlangOTP')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:External:datetimepicker')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
}
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
remove it and then run it

Comment: use this:
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
instead of:  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

Comment: @Filnik:- You have to use grade - "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'" OR more latest version also and import file is --import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; Then u will get AppCompatActivity. Its working fine here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Finally

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:External:ErlangOTP')
    compile project(':gsd_droid_common:External:datetimepicker')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync your Project`** .Hope it will helps .

Comment: I choose your solution because it actually worked and the clean-rebuild-restart thing, with the missing part I noted below, just worked

Answer (score 2):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use grade - "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'" OR new latest version also and import file is --import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; Then u will get AppCompatActivity. Its working fine here..

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything worked just fined.

The problem was this. I only added

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

At the beginning (I wanted to do it automatically with alt+enter but it wasn't possible) and fixed every compileSdkVersion from 22 to 23 of every module. Now it works just fine.

Comment: Good elaborations .Happy coding +1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Create a new project with blank Activity, compare the wrong gradle and the gradle of new project, change the wrong to the new one of these 2 lines, something like:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

AppCompat version seems have to set to local compileSdkVersion !